# response.redirect not redirecting to full domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, redirect, response.redirect

I'm having an issue Redirecting to the same domain.

For example, the redirection takes place on **ServerA.Domain.com/Folder/application.aspx**. However, the program redirects me to **ServerA/Folder/application.aspx**.

The application works fine on this domain, but I'm forced to relogin.

What can I do to force the redirection to the same domain??

I am using asp.net 3.5

**Added**
My Redirect looks as follows:

```
Response.Redirect("/Folder/application.aspx?");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you just add the tilde (~) character and a call to ResolveClientUrl to the redirect?

```
Response.Redirect(this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Folder/application.aspx?"));
```

Does that take care of the problem?

Comment: That will give him the same results as just doing `/Folder` the application see's the sub domain as a folder in the domain, which is exactly what it is.

Comment: @Nick, you are correct. I had forgotten the call to ResolveClientUrl which I've now added. ResolveClientUrl returns a fully qualified URL which might take care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your on a sub domain trying to redirect to a folder on the sub domain. I believe you need to use the fully qualified URL:

```
Response.Redirect("http://ServerA.Domain.com/Folder/application.aspx?");
```

What's happening is your sub domain is a folder on the main site, which your telling your app to redirect to. It doesn't know that you have a sub domain set up which accesses that folder by default.

**Update:**
Try using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.xxxxx` and then appending to that. This way you can probably get your sub domain route and redirect in the format you want.

Comment: Yeah I can do this but I'd have to hardcode the string because this needs to be ran on an array of servers. I believe If i coded it like this : Response.Redirect("Application.aspx"); I shouldn't have the problem. Wouldn't you think?

Comment: Your users may conveniently access your web site at `ServerA.Domain.com/Folder/application.aspx` but the physical structure probably looks like this `http://Domain.com/ServerA/Folder/application.aspx`, however, you may play around with the differant variations of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

`Server.Transfer("/Folder/application.aspx?");`

Answer (score 0):

ResolveClientUrl returns a relative path to the current url;
ResolveUrl returns the absolute path. So ResolveUrl may work better in case it is called within a usercontrol under another folder:

```
Response.Redirect(this.ResolveUrl("~/Folder/application.aspx?"));
```